# Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Define $T \in \mathcal{L(F^2)}$ by $$ T(w,z) = (z,w)$$Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$.

An eigenvalue is defined as $\lambda \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$ where $v \neq 0$. Expanding the definition, I get the following system of equations

$$z = \lambda w \\ w = \lambda z \tag 1.$$

Now I can simplify this system by substituting $w$ for $z$ values to get $$ z = \lambda^2 z \\
0 = \lambda^2 z - z \\
0 = z(\lambda^2 - 1)$$

Solving for $\lambda$ gives $ \lambda = \pm 1$ so the two eigenvalues are $1, -1$.

To find the corresponding eigenvectors, from (1) I think the vector I get is $(z, w) = (\lambda ^2 z, \lambda z) = (z,z)$ when $\lambda = 1)$ and

$(z, w) = (\lambda ^2 z, \lambda z) = (z,-z)$ when $\lambda = -1)$

However I am not sure if I found the corresponding eigenvectors. What would be a way I could check for myself that these are correct?

Comment: To check that these are correct: note that $T(z,z) = (z,z)$, which means that $T$ does indeed scale the vector $(z,z)$ with a factor 1, which is exactly the eigenvalue you found. The other one can be done analogously.

Comment: You can do a geometric sanity check. The transformation is a reflection in the line $z=w$. What lines through the origin are their own images under this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check. If $(x,y)$ is an eigenvector of $\textsf T$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, then $(x,y)$ satisfies
$$(y,x)=\textsf{T}(x,y)=1(x,y)=(x,y)$$
that is, $x=y$. The vectors $(x,y)$ that satisfies $x=y$ are exactly the vectors living in the span of $\{(1,1)\}$. Similarly, the eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$ are the vectors in $\operatorname{span}\big(\{(1,-1)\}\big)$.